# Graduate Student in Nursing Research

Tags: inference, nonparametric

I am doing a research proposal comparing the rates of venous thromboembolisms in post operative surgical patients. Two groups are being studied and were assigned by the type of drug they were prescribed from their physician. The two types of drugs compared are oral anticoagulants and low molecular weight heparin. I am doing this research proposal to find out what group of participants, the oral anticoagulants or the low molecular weight heparin group, had less events of clots. My professor wants me to choose a non-parametric or parametric tests to use for my statstical analysis. Any help would be welcomed as I am confused between t-tests and etc.

Comment: I would be most concerned about non-randomized assignment of patients to treatment.  How do you plan to control for that?  Do you have plans to perform a randomized control trial or use a propensity score approach to control for confounding?

Comment: It sounds like your outcome of interest is the rate of clots. Is this a continuous measure, or binary (yes/no)? In other words, for an individual patient, is your measurement of clotting numeric (e.g. the degree of clotting in that patient, the blood levels of compounds related to clotting in that patient, etc.) or is it categorical (did this patient experience a clot, yes or no)? The answer to this question will inform your choice of statistical test.

Comment: I was using a quasi-experiment. Data will be collected over an 8 week period.  Participants were taught the signs and symptoms of VTEs, including deep vein thrombosis and pulmonary embolism, and benefits of early mobilization. Once the treatment plan begins, participants will have scheduled follow-up visits to the clinic where they will be assessed by the APRN. My professor allowed me to use a quasi-experimental as I am using questionnaires, follow-up visits, and a wells critiera score as instruments to help in my research.

Comment: To Rose- At the scheduled follow up visits, as the researcher I was collecting blood samples of specific tests that measure for VTEs. I am new to the whole research world and appreciate everyones feedback.

Comment: To Rose- I would say that I am going to use the categorial approach and ask...did this patient experience a clot?

Comment: It sounds like this might be a relatively preliminary study that will yield guidance about future study design rather than a firm conclusion. In such a case you should think of getting as much information from the available data as possible. The analysis of a preliminary study does not need to be pre-planned and so you can gather the data and then decide. I would suggest an emphasis on interval estimates to begin with.

Comment: @MichaelLew- Yes, I believe if I understand you correctly, this is a preliminary study in that we are not ever going to conduct the study. Do you mind elaboarating on what you mean by interval estimates please?

Comment: My professor is requesting this "Discuss the test you will use to address the study hypothesis and which measures of central tendency you will report for demographic variables". So basically I am thinking along the lines of t-tests, ANOVA tests, etc.

Comment: Please amend your title to give some hint of your problem, not your CV

Answer (score 0):

A quick answer for comparing two groups is the Mann-Whitney U. I recommend that over the T test. Its more robust to non-normal distributions (which is pretty common in real world data collection). If you are doing a repeated measures design (i.e. you are taking blood samples from the same patient multiple times), then there are more appropriate methods. I can give a little more guidance if that is the case.

Comment: Yes I will be using blood more than once.